# WPF: UserControl.IsFocused will not set

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I created a WPF UserControl, that handles all `GotFocus`/`LostFocus` events of its child controls. I call the `OnGotFocus`/`OnLostFocus` of the `UserControl`, but the `IsFocused` property of the UserControl will not set:

```
void MyUserControl_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (UIElement control in (Content as Panel).Children)
    {
        control.LostFocus += control_LostFocus;
        control.GotFocus += control_GotFocus;
    }
}

void control_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsFocused)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        OnGotFocus(e);
    }
}

void control_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool hasAnythingTheFocus = false;

    foreach (UIElement control in (Content as Panel).Children)
    {
        if (control.IsFocused)
        {
            hasAnythingTheFocus = true;
        }
    }

    if (!hasAnythingTheFocus)
    {
        OnLostFocus(e);
    }
}
```

How can I set it?

Comment: You can't set it. `IsFocused` is read-only. Why would you want it to be set? do you have any triggers binding to it?

Comment: Why does it matter, why? I want! I know, that IsFocused is read-only, that's why I'm here!

Comment: It should matter because usually when you post a question and someone ask you a question about it, he is trying get some more information about your problem to try and help you better. But when you answer like that, it really doesn't make people want to help you, atleast I don't. good luck.

Comment: See the comment under @Sheridan

Comment: +1 I second @Omribitan's comment... you need to help us to help you.

Comment: "How can I set it?" - I want just that! I'm talkin about the logical focus (IsFocused), and I want just set it. No more!

Comment: On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isfocused(v=vs.110).aspx) Page for UIElement.Focus it says, you need to call Focus method to set focus programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `IsFocused` you can use `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`

Answer (score 3):

use the event **UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged** and it should worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, but I want to set the logical focus too!

Comment: The OnGotFocus method is fired in response to the GotFocus routed event that have the bubbling routing. This method is not fired because the corresponding event is processed at the embedded child control level. You can check GotFocus/LostFocus events. These event should be fired for your TextBox and UserControl as well.

Comment: Yes, I get these events, but I want to bind some feature on the IsFocused property of the UserControl, and wold like to set it via some calls or somehow, but I can not figure out, how :S

Comment: You could try Keyboard.Focus().

Answer (score 0):

The `GotFocus` method will be called when the relevant control receives logical focus... from the [`UIElement.GotFocus` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Logical focus differs from keyboard focus if focus is deliberately forced by using a method call but the previous keyboard focus exists in a different scope. In this scenario, keyboard focus remains where it is and the element where a Focus method is called still gets logical focus.
>
> A more precise interpretation of this event is that it is raised when the value of the IsFocused property of an element in the route is changed from false to true.
>
> Because this event uses bubbling routing, the element that receives focus might be a child element instead of the element where the event handler is actually attached. Check the Source in the event data to determine the actual element that gained focus.
>   it will get focus when the user clicks on the relevant control in the UI and/or when you call control.Focus() in your code. The `IsFocused` is `readonly` and cannot be set.

Comment: Ok, but I want to create a UserControl, that beheaves just like an another control: I want to right handle the logical and keyboad focus. Can you send me an example?

Comment: Please add an edit to your question (not in a comment) and *clearly* explain what you want.

Comment: You've already been told... *you can't set it because it is read only*. You've been asked to provide more information twice in this post now. Furthermore, it has been explained to you *why* you should provide more information and on both occasions, you have failed to do so. As you are not willing to help us solve *your* problem, then quite frankly, I am no longer willing to spend my time trying to help you. You sir, have a terrible attitude for someone asking for help.

Comment: The property is read-only, but the logical focus... I think a usercontrol can also have the logical focus. Or not?

Comment: Dude, as far as I am concerned, you've missed your chance. You *could* have explained what your overall requirements were and we *could* have explained to you how you could have achieved them, but *you* decided not to... *you* decided to be unhelpful and rude, so now @Omribitan and I decided that you were not worth helping. Maybe on your next question, you can change your attitude and get more help?

Comment: On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isfocused(v=vs.110).aspx) Page for `UIElement.Focus` it  says, you need to call `Focus` method to set focus programmatically.

Comment: @sthotakura, thanks but I am well aware of that. Maybe you should tell the question author instead.

Comment: @Sheridan my bad, I thought I was adding comment to the question. Sorry :(

Comment: @sthotakura, it's not a problem at all.